# The battery drains when the laptop is turned off

Tags: gnome, power-management, laptop, hp, battery

When I turn off my laptop using the terminal with the command `sudo poweroff -f` there are no battery discharge issues. When I turn off my laptop using GUI the laptop battery continues to drain.
HP Laptop 15s-eq1320ur.
I have tried different kernel versions and different versions of Ubuntu, but the problem remains unresolved:

Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu 22.04, Ubuntu 23.04

Kernel 5.19, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4

Comment: You mention trying various Ubuntu version & kernel versions, but gave no specifics. Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choices; but we don't know what product/release you're asking about. I would try and avoid `poweroff -f` & instead cleanly shutdown, and also suggest you explore what the issue is; eg. I'd use SysRq commands to *safely* power off with clean file *sync*. Did you explore logs on your *unstated* product & *unstated* kernel stack attempts?

Comment: your problem is hardware related. the OS is dead when a laptop is turned off.  Hence why diff. OS and kernels do the same. 1st thing to do: turn off usb power off in bios.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for your advice. I edited my question. I dont have enough experience to explore logs.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for your advice. Usb is turned off. Also, when i used Windows, there was no problem